# Call function from another component (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

(React)
I have a function in a component (class called SideLogo)

```
toggleStatus(flag = !this.state.turned) {
    this.setState({turned: flag})
}
```

And I have another function in a component

```
_enterHandler() {
    SideLogo.toggleStatus()
}
```

I’m trying to call toggleStatus()

Comment: props is how you pass data including functions... share the complete code for both components...

Comment: From a different component?  Ona a user event, or when the component mounts?

Comment: @stever different component, the different component is acting when I’m scrolling the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SakoBu already mentioned you can expose a function using the props.
Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wzhdampx/

In your other component:

```
  _enterHandler() {
    this.toggleStatus();
  }

  render() {
    return <SideLogo toggleStatus={func => this.toggleStatus = func} />;
  }
```

In the SideLog component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { toggleStatus } = this.props;
    if (toggleStatus) {
        toggleStatus(this.toggleStatus);
    }
}
```